# Многомерный динамический массив char си

Tags: c, массивы, char

Есть файл txt со словами в три столбика (столбики разделены табуляцией) и изменяющимся количеством строк. Есть поток `fopen`, назовём его `f`. Подсчет количества строк в переменную counter уже написан, а теперь нужен массив строк. Вроде бы его следует писать как `char dict[counter][3][lenght]`, но:
1. Является ли массив выше табличкой с `counter` строками и `i` столбцами, содержащей слова длины `length`?
2. Как правильно объявить этот массив, если память под него должна выделяться функцией `new`?
3. В идеале, словом является последовательность букв, знаков препинания и пробелов,  границы - начало/конец строки и знаки табуляции. Как можно сделать так, чтобы длина слова считывалась в переменную `length`, а само слово - в ячейку массива?
4. Когда я обращаюсь к слову, то обращение идет к `dict[i][j]`, `i` от 0 до `counter`, `j` от 0 до 3, так? Ну, например, слово в пятой строке во втором столбце имеет адрес `dict[5][2]`?

Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char dict[counter][3][lenght]` - это массив из `counter` массивов, где каждый массив представляет собой 3 массива, каждый из которых имеет длину `length`.

Если вы запутываетесь в длинных типах - используйте `typedef`, не стесняйтесь. Например

```
typedef char word[length];  // word - слово, length символов
typedef word line[3];       // line - строка из трех слов
typedef line text[counter]; // text - counter строк...
```

По второму вопросу - какая же функция `new` в C? Вы имеете в виду `malloc`? А если у вас C++ и `new` - то лучше использовать `vector`. А `malloc` - просто вызывайте `malloc(sizeod(dict))`. Но вы должны точно знать, что никакое слово не будет длиннее `length-1` символов, например. Иначе лучше брать массив `char* dict[counter][3]` - и выделять память для каждой строки.

> Когда я обращаюсь к слову, то обращение идет к dict[i][j], i от 0 до
>   counter, j от 0 до 3, так? Ну, например, слово в пятой строке во
>   втором столбце имеет адрес dict[5][2]?

Нет, в C вся нумерация от 0 - да, но всего ведь элементов у вас `counter` - значит, `i` имеет значения от 0 до `counter-1`. И, соответственно, слово в пятой строке, втором столбце - `dict[4][1]`.

Что касается того, как считывать строки... Тут есть разные варианты. Лично я бы считывал всю строку, а потом делил по символам табуляции, получал длину с помощью `strlen`.